# Subtle difference between sort and sort_by

Tags: ruby, sorting

This is not a trick question:

```
[1,2,3].sort_by { |x, y| x <=> y }
=> [1, 2, 3] 

[1,2,3].sort_by { |x, y| y <=> x }
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

What's going on here? I would have expected the arrays to be opposite one another (as they are with sort and the same parameters).

Comment: Take a look at: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by you will definitely find your answer here. For future reference consult the ruby-doc your bound to find your answer here :)

Comment: I read the docs; just didn't notice the difference between `sort` and `sort_by`. But I do always appreciate being told to RTFM. That's the spirit of StackOverflow.

Comment: doc link updated: https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Enumerable:sort_by

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`#sort_by` should just take one block parameter, an item from the array, and sorts based on the result of the block.

When passing it two block parameters, the second is set to `nil` and thus all block results are like `1 <=> nil` which is `nil` so the order of the array is unchanged.

```
[1, 3, 2].sort_by { |x| x } # sorts using x <=> y
=> [1, 2, 3]

[1, 3, 2].sort_by { |x, y| x <=> y } # sorts using nil <=> nil
=> [1, 3, 2]
```

Comment: Ah yes Ruby blocks are like Ruby procs - they are not strict with num of arguments passed. If they were OP would error out immediately which I think is much better.

Answer (score 7):

```
[1, 3, 2].sort_by { |x| x }
=> [1, 2, 3] 

[1, 3, 2].sort_by { |x| -x }
=> [3, 2, 1] 

[1, 3, 2].sort
=> [1, 2, 3] 

[1, 3, 2].sort.reverse
=> [3, 2, 1] 

[1, 3, 2].sort { |x, y| x <=> y }
=> [1, 2, 3] 

[1, 3, 2].sort { |x, y| y <=> x }
=> [3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Duh...I meant to pass the block to `sort`, not `sort_by` -- which, instead of failing noisily does all sorts of unusual things, especially if you're sorting objects (as I was in my actual code). Your answer was right (and first) but I picked @looby's because he pointed out that `y = nil`